# Best way to cancel a unix call (using SSH library) via the UI in a synchronous application in C#?

Tags: c#, unix, .net-4.0, ssh, synchronous

My program (.NET 4.0) uses a 3rd party SSH library ([SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/), works great so far) to send a unix command that is constructed based on the user's choices in the UI, waits for the respose and outputs it.  My problem arises when sometimes the unix response just "hangs" for lack of a better term, in which cases my program is stuck waiting.  In unix you can just escape that command (for me CTRL-C) and try again, but when using a library, I'm not sure how to provide the equivelent.

Another problem is that the UI thread is locked when this is happening, so even if there was some sort of "Cancel" button the user wouldn't be able to click on it.  I looked into BackgroundWorker and Threading, but that doesn't really make sense because my operation is synchronous - the program has to wait for the response so it can parse it (format, color, ect).

Any thoughts on this would much appriciated, thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak specifically to the SSH.NET and how you can cancel a command via that library, but here's how I would approach it.

I would launch the "command" on a Task, which is essentially a separate thread.  Here's my sample code:

```
private Task _commandTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

protected void SendCommand(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(_commandTask != null)
        return; // Can't run the task twice

    _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _commandTask = new Task(SendSshCommand, _cancellation.Token);
    _commandTask.ContinueWith(FinishCommand, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    _commandTask.Start();

    // returning control to the UI thread now
}

protected void CancelCommand(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(_commandTask == null)
        return;

    _cancellation.Cancel();
}

private static void SendSshCommand() 
{
    // Send your SSH Commands here
}

private void FinishCommand(Task task) 
{
   // Update your UI here

   // remove this task
   _commandTask = null;
   _cancellation = null;
}
```

So the `SendCommand` method would be invoked from some event on your UI (button click I assume).  It creates a `CancellationTokenSource` and a new [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28VS.100%29.aspx).  This task calls the `SendSshCommand` method on a separate thread.  We then create a task continuation with the `ContinueWith` method. Passing in the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncrhonizationContext()` tells the continuation task that we want to execute on the UI's thread instead of a separate thread.  This is important because if we're not on the UI thread we cannot access any of the UI controls.

The `CancelCommand` would be called from your cancel button, and it simply tells the `_commandTask` to stop executing.

Now this isn't 100%, I'm sure you're going to have state that you need to pass around to the tasks, and there are [Generic Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) structures to help you with that.  Also, in your `FinishCommand`, you're going to want to check to make sure the task was completed, not cancelled, and didn't throw an exception.  Read up on Tasks and the TPL in .Net 4 and you'll see how to do that.

It's also worth noting, that I'm not sure what will happen with your SSH.NET library after the cancellation.  I would assume it would just disconnect the SSH session, which in turn would end the process on the Unix machine.  But again, I'm not familiar with that particular library so you'll have to do some testing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I need to read up on Tasks first as this is my first exposure to them, but this looks promising!

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Im trying to implement your solution, but Im getting an error on the _commandTask.ContinueWith(stuff) line, says there's no overload matching those arguments... Im currently reading up on Tasks now but I dont know enough about em to see if this is just some sort of typo or not, thanks!

Comment: What is "stuff", it should be a delegate or action.

Comment: stuff is what you put in there, just didnt want to copy/paste it into my comment to make is shorter, its exactly that same line from your example code

Comment: Sorry, had some pretty bad typo's in there.  I updated the code for you.  That's what I get for writing code in the SO editor rather than VS. (I'm too spoiled by auto complete)

Comment: Haha no worries, thanks for the update.  Couple questions: Does SendSshCommand need to be static, and how do I get my return vaule from that function into FinishCommand (or is the result contained in the FinishCommand's Task argument)?

Comment: If you want to return a result from the task, look at the generic form of the Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx).  The generic parameter will be your return value.  None of the methods _need_ to be static if you need to use instance members.  If you want to move this conversation to email, feel free to email me, my address is in my profile.

Comment: Thanks again, I sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library but if you have one SSH session, that is, the same shell then launch the command as a background task and cancel it with a kill %1

Launch:-

> command &

Cancel:-

> kill %1

This does require it to be in the same shell of course.

CTRL-C is ASCII 3 if you've got a stream type interface to the shell sending that might work.